# Vanilla JS .style working but jQuery .css is not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i were to comment out the jquery .style and replace it with the currently commented line the code works fine. I do not understand the issue as they both accomplish the same thing. This might be a conceptual issue more than a coding one but I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>


  <div id="header">

    <div id="navimg-holder">
        <img src="images/navimg.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div id="navlist">

        <div class="navelm">
            <a href=""> <p> Home </p> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navelm">
            <a href=""> <p> Contant </p> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navelm">
            <a href=""> <p> Experience </p> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navelm">
            <a href=""> <p> Interests </p> </a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="logo-holder">

    </div>
    <div id="socialmedia-div">

        <div class="socialmedia-holder"> 
            <a href="https://facebook.com"> <img src="images/social1.jpg" alt="" > </a>
        </div>

        <div class="socialmedia-holder" id="second-socialmedia">
            <a href="https://twitter.com"> <img src="images/social2.jpg" alt="" id="twitter"> </a>
        </div>

        <div class="socialmedia-holder" id="third-socialmedia">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com"> <img src="images/social3.jpg" alt="" id="insta"> </a>
        </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content1">

  </div>

<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>
</body>
</html>


/*    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * CSS * * * * * * * *  * * *   */

 #navlist
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 140px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navelm
{
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.navelm a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navelm p
{
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Palatino;
}


/*  * * * * * * * * * * *  JAVASCRIPT * * * * * * */

$("#navimg-holder img").click(showMenu);

function showMenu()
{
    $('.navelm').each(function()
        {
            this.css("background-color","white");
           /* this.style.backgroundColor = "white";  */
        });

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` is a JavaScript DOM object. `this` has no method `.css` to it. You need to wrap it in your jQuery object.

```
$(this).css("background-color","white");
```

For that to work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need an `each` , can simply do:

```
function showMenu(){
    $('.navelm').css("background-color","white");
}
```

jQuery will internally loop over all matching elements and apply the style to all

Answer (score 0):

`this` isn't a jQuery object, it's a plain DOM Node, you have to wrap it in $().

Here's three ways to do this:

```
$elements.each(function(i, el){
    $(this).css('key', value);
    //or
    $(el).css('key', value);
    //or
    $(someOtherNodeListOrCollection[i]).css('key', value);
});
```

Keep in mind you can do multiple attributes

```
$item.css({
   'key1': value,
   'key2': value2
});
```

Or even better for performance and separating concerns: use a selecting class, with addClass or removeClass.